# Stateless web services do not work in HTTPS for Glassfish 3.1

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, https, wsdl, glassfish

I still consider myself new to Java webservices, and I have hit a real roadblock that I cannot overcome.

I am trying to deploy a `@Stateless` Web Service and access it's WSDL over https.  Whenever I attempt to access it I get the following error in the browser:

```
Error generating artifacts for the following WSDL https://localhost:8181/TestService/Test?WSDL

Possible causes can be invoking https when the application is not configured for security
```

The console is showing the following errors:

```
INFO: parsing WSDL...

WARNING: Invalid request scheme for Endpoint Test. Expected http . Received https
INFO: [ERROR] Premature end of file.
INFO:   line 1 of https://localhost:8181/TestService/Test?WSDL
WARNING: Invalid request scheme for Endpoint Test. Expected http . Received https
WARNING: MEX0008:Failed to parse metadata returned from server at https://localhost:8181/TestService/Test?WSDL using protocol SOAP_1_2. Continuing attempts.
WARNING: Invalid request scheme for Endpoint Test. Expected http . Received https
WARNING: MEX0008:Failed to parse metadata returned from server at https://localhost:8181/TestService/Test?WSDL using protocol SOAP_1_1. Continuing attempts.
WARNING: Invalid request scheme for Endpoint Test. Expected http . Received https
WARNING: MEX0008:Failed to parse metadata returned from server at https://localhost:8181/TestService/Test?WSDL/mex using protocol SOAP_1_2. Continuing attempts.
WARNING: Invalid request scheme for Endpoint Test. Expected http . Received https
WARNING: MEX0008:Failed to parse metadata returned from server at https://localhost:8181/TestService/Test?WSDL/mex using protocol SOAP_1_1. Continuing attempts.
INFO: [ERROR] Premature end of file.
Failed to read the WSDL document: https://localhost:8181/TestService/Test?WSDL, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>.
INFO: [ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s): 
 At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.
INFO:   Failed to parse the WSDL.
INFO: Invoking wsimport with https://localhost:8181/TestService/Test?WSDL
SEVERE: wsimport failed
```

Again, this is **ONLY** happening when accessing it over HTTPS.  Regular HTTP is fine.  However, if I were to remove the `@Stateless` annotation, it works just fine over https.  It fails when I add the `@Stateless` annotation.

I need the `@Stateless` annotation since I will be working with JMS Queues, and you need it when doing that.

Below is the code for my class:

```
package service.test;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@Stateless
@WebService
public class Test
{
    public String hello()
    {
        return "Hello!";
    }

    @WebMethod
    public int addNumbers(int number1, int number2)
    {
        return number1 + number2;
    }
}
```

So far at this point, I have never needed to utilize any web descriptors.  Everything I have done is by default handled in Eclipse automatically.  Do I have to do anything special with the descriptor files?  If so, which ones?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an odd issue that I never really figured out the cause of.  Oddly enough, this issue worked itself out in the end by not needing `@Stateless`.

Answer (score 0):

Https uses port 443 by default.  If your webservice is listening on port 8181, it won't see the https requests.

Comment: The HTTPS component for the webservice is set to listen on port 8181 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: do you have your servers certs issuer in your truststore? It can be an ugly ssl problem. (although the fact that it works without @Stateless kind of contradicts my theory)

just a guess...

Comment: I am using a self-signed certificate.  I have both a truststore that is the same as my regular keystore.  Oddly enough, I was able to use JMS Queues without needing `@Stateless`, which is strange, since I always needed it in the past...